# Yahoo MAILTO link in HTML doesn't support BCC?

Tags: html, yahoo-mail

I am trying to create a normal MAILTO link in HTML with BCC on, but it seems like everything works except the BCC parameter. Can anyone help in this regard?

`mailto:?subject=this is the subject&body=this is the message&to=tooooooo@email.com&cc=abc@email.com&bcc=tim@eamil.com`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Try the below code in HTML

```
mailto:example@mail.com?cc=cc@mail.com&bcc=bcc@mail.com&subject=This is the subjest message&body=Body can be written here!
```